# Making status-animarum synonym of vital-records?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Can someone please suggest [status-animarum](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-animarum) be a synonym for [vital-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vital-records)?

I'd suggest it myself, but my reputation does not permit.

Comment: The records that had been tagged [tag:status-animarum] were essentially family group sheets. A better pre-existing tag match may have been [tag:family-register]. However, [tag:family-register] hasn't been used as much as it could have.

Comment: @bgwiehle I agree, can we get the merge instead made to family-register?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have performed a merge (moderator tool) of [status-animarum](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-animarum) with [vital-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vital-records) leaving the former as a synonym.

Comment: See bgwiehle's comment above.